# Where can I get windows 8 pro ISO file?

Tags: windows-8

Where can I get windows 8 pro ISO file (I want it fully activated so that I don't bother to copy/paste a serial )? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: So, do you have a license already?

Comment: Yes, of course .

Comment: Call Microsoft.

Comment: This looks too much like a request for a pirated version of Windows. If there's a legitimate use case, please explain it.

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere, any legal copy of Windows 8 has to be activated. If you ever come across an ISO file with a version of Windows 8 that is already activated it is illegal to use it, regardless of how many licenses you have.

Comment: OMG, I have come across many activated ISO files of windows 7 and tons of software  .I'm going to jail. It seems that I should hide now .

Comment: Any pre-activated software usually entails a pirated version.